# How to read yaml payload in request body in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, yaml

I know that we can read yaml file in nodejs using `js-yaml` and `yaml.load` . But how to read the yaml content when it is being parsed in nodejs api request payload.

currently my simple nodejs app that is built on express accepts only json.

How to make the same api to accept yaml payload in request body

Comment: Use Header Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
I mean, it might not help you but others.

Answer (score 0):

Your application by default accepts all file types. The file type is set in the `Content-Type` request header, and you can use `req.is()` in express to check if the request is of a certain file type. So instead of making your application accept YAML, you need to make your application give an error if given any other file type.

You can use the following code for that:

```js
if(!req.is('application/yaml')){
  res.status(400).send('Not YAML!')
  return
} else {
  // Do other stuff
}
```

Note that all YAML content need not be sent under the tag of `application/yaml`. You can use AND statements to work with all the possible options:

```js
if(!req.is('application/yaml') && !req.is('application/x-yaml') &&
   !req.is('application/yml') && !req.is('application/x-yml') &&
   !req.is('text/yaml') && !req.is('text/yml') &&
   !req.is('text/x-yaml') && !req.is('text/x-yml')){
  res.status(400).send('Not YAML!')
  return
} else {
  // Do other stuff
}
```

You can get the sent data like this:

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: ['application/yaml', 'application/x-yaml', 'application/yml', 'application/x-yml', 'text/yaml', 'text/yml', 'text/x-yaml', 'text/x-yml'] }))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.body) // Gives the YAML content as a string
})
```

Note: You need to run `npm i body-parser` to install the `body-parser` extension for Express.js first.

Use `bodyParser.raw()` to get the data as a Buffer instead of a string.

Comment: thanks once it is yaml, how to read the data from the request? as req.data is giving error

Comment: sorry not req.data, its req.body is giving undefined